# Need to display sensitive data output variables in terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure

The following code snippet is my terraform configuration to create an Azure SignalR Service:

```
output "signalrserviceconnstring" {
  value = azurerm_signalr_service.mysignalrservice.primary_connection_string
  description = "signalR service's primary connection string"
  sensitive = true
}
```

I got an error when `sensitive = true` is not included but I still do not see the output results on the console. What's the solution or workaround for this problem?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

The entire point of `sensitive = true` is to prevent the values from being displayed on the console every time you run `terraform apply`. You have to output the sensitive value explicitly, like this:

```
terraform output signalrserviceconnstring
```

I highly suggest reading [the documentation](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/terraform/outputs).

Comment: As far as I know this doesn't work for planned changes. Is there something similar to verify if changes to sensitive values are correct before they are applied?

Answer (score 61):

You could use function `nonsensitive` like this

```
    output "mysecret" {
      value = nonsensitive(var.mysecret)
    }
```

Comment: This is also useful for the interactive `$ terraform console` command. Without formally declaring an output, `> nonsensitive(var.mysecret)` will print the secret!

Comment: This is also useful when testing with `terraform plan` command to test if the output string is what you expect to be.
After tests you just remove the output so nothing will be saved.

Comment: This is the only thing I could make work.  Even setting `sensitive = false` terraform refused to print it.  Really hard to debug when you can't see anything, and it's even more maddening because I didn't mark it sensitive in the first place!  Terraform just decided it was sensitive because (I assume) of some of the names inside the contents.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to get a sensitive value from the *state* rather than from the *output*, use this:

```
$ terraform show -json | \
  jq '.values.root_module.resources[] | select(.address == "tls_private_key.ssh_key")' 
{
  "address": "tls_private_key.server_ssh_key",
  "type": "tls_private_key",
  "name": "server_ssh_key",
  ...
  "values": {
    "algorithm": "ED25519",
    "private_key_openssh": "-----BEGIN OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----\n...",
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: I believe this is the best solution that fits in every use cases